# Pin chat to the sidebar on main site?

Tags: feature-request, chat

Can we pin the link to the chatroom to the sidebar on the main site? It does not always appear.

This was asked by another user in chat and discussed (I can't find it now, of course) and I thought it was a great idea, because I often also have a hard time finding the button.

Perhaps it'll make chat livelier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not something that the moderators can do on a per-site basis. So, I am not really sure if there is much we can say about this matter.

Scrolling through meta.SE the closest related question I could find was this: [How do moderators permanently add Site Chat Room to main page sidebar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279609/how-do-moderators-permanently-add-site-chat-room-to-main-page-sidebar) which I believe Loong already linked you to in chat. Of course, you are most welcome to post your suggestion on meta.SE.

Personally in my experience I cannot find any logical pattern as to when chat shows up in the sidebar. As such I always access chat via the Stack Exchange logo in the top-left:

[image]